# How to send different datatypes AJAX request in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I write AJAX code in javascript, i can specify to request different datatypes from server, like plain, xml, json, script, using Rails, how to I specify different datatypes using remote:true?

Thanks

Comment: AJAX is JavaScript it stands for  asynchronous JavaScript and XML

Comment: In your controller action just render the data type like this `render :json`

Comment: @Cyzanfar i know, but how to setup ajax request in the view?